# The [underscores] tag is in the process of being cleaned

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

*The Phase #2 of the burnination process described  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system, but instead the tag needs to be cleaned up and disambiguated. The tag is in the process of being curated. Please see the progress answer to keep track of progress.*

---

I just discovered that we have a [underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores). This seems like a fairly useless meta tag to me, as it's generally used to indicate that the OP wants to have or remove an underscore from their output, and as such is no different from [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a) (for example).

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   It seems like a fairly obvious meta tag to me. The entire wiki for the tag page is as follows.

   > The underscore, Unicode Character 'LOW LINE' (U+005F) <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> on a keyboard.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   In the loosest possible sense of the word, yes, apart from that No.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   I certainly can't find any information it could possibly add. I doubt there are many people who are subject matter experts in the matters of the underscore.

   The only post that comes close to needing the tag is the top rated question for the tag that asks about the usage of `__` (dunderscore) functions in Python, but even there it's mostly superfluous.

   There are 2 followers and 149 questions.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   It could easily be confused with [underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore.js).

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: `double underscore` seems equally redundant.  Just a bunch of questions asking "why double underscores are used in situation X in language Y".  The tag doesn't add anything.

Comment: "...experts in the matters of the underscore" I use _it_ regularly and know _it_ fairly well. I can even find _it_ with closed eyes. Is this sufficient to be an expert on _it_?

Comment: Apparently one can't search for `_`, so for questions like “what does the underscore mean in this context?” typing it literally won't help. But I think using the word instead of the symbol, as I did phrasing the question, would be more appropriate. And people who'd otherwise be using the tag might want to make sure that the word underscore occurs in their post. That aspect might be worth considering when removing occurrences of this tag.

Comment: Well, of course a Python developer doesn't care about underscore.js :P. I would say it might not be a bad idea to synonymize `underscore` with `underscore.js` and call it a day.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Except that pretty much none of the answers currently using it are talking about underscore.js

Comment: Yeah, obviously my reading skills need work because the OP is actually talking about `underscores`, with an `s`...

Comment: This is not a meta tag. A meta tag describes the question _itself_ -- for example [burninate-request] -- not the subject of the question. "underscore" would be a meta tag only if someone were to use it to indicate that the post should be emphasized somehow.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +69/-3. A1 (neutral?!): +69/-1

Comment: @BhargavRao: I am looking at this tag. Is there another tag for reserved name classes, because this seems to be what the tag is about. Hint: identifiers starting with one or more underscores are where reserved names live.

Comment: Actually I am also not so sure @Joshua. I am fine with having a tag for that. Also the dunder methods which the OP mentions is called magic methods, which has it's own tag, and is quite on topic... I guess a disambiguation is enough here, rather than a burn, but I am not able to find other valid usages of the underscore tag.. Feel free to add an answer with your views. (I probably will be adding an answer sometime later after reading up a bit and researching more).

Comment: If one underscore isn't enough, you can always use [tag:double-underscore]s.

Comment: It looks like `undersocres` is also the name of a WordPress theme that already has its [own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores-wp).

Comment: The tag wiki isn't even true for all keyboards. On French keyboards, the underscore is Shift+8. If the tag isn't burninated, it should be edited to say "on some keyboards" or something similar (or that part could be removed).

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +145/-12. A1 (neutral?!): +102/-4 (deleted). A2 (asking to cleanup): +41/-17. A3 (Yes): +8/-12. A4 (asking to rename):  +15/-4. A5 (asking to disambiguate): +28/-2. The community has voted against burninating the tag. However there is no clear consensus on what should be done. Given the top two answers are asking for cleanup/disambiguate, the middle path is to do both. The request as such is declined. If new evidence later warrants re-evaluation of this decision, a new proposal can be started.

Answer (score 30):

I agree with the answers of Joshua and Machavity that the tag requires just a disambiguation and a clean up. Some other tags which can be used instead of [underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores) are:

- [magic-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-methods) -  for the dunder methods, like `__str__`, which are "magically" called when `str` is called.
- [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) - For the `_` method in [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).
- [underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore.js) - for the Underscore.js related questions.
- [underscores-wp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores-wp) - for the Underscores theme in WordPress.
- [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) - for the usage of underscore in variable names and snake case, if warranted. In many cases, the [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore) can just be dropped.

and finally whatever we agree for the underscore character that is used to mention private methods. That will also be used for the sunder methods (single underscore).

There are a couple of usages of underscore, which I am not sure which tag is needed, or whether a tag is even needed:

- The usage of `_` as in order to access the last value in the Python interpreter (I feel that it does not really require the [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore) tag).
- The usage of `_` in order to separate literals in Python 3.6.
- For the wildcard variable `_`, which is used to ignore the value sent into it.

Comment: I think the use of `_` in identifier names instead of Pascal or camel case falls into [tag:identifier] and maybe [tag:coding-convention]

Comment: @Ben, I think using [tag:naming-conventions] would be a better idea here.

Comment: That sounds good too.  I just don't see the value in (1) separating case from other naming choices and (2) having made that separation, somehow throwing a punctuation choice into the case bucket

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense @BenVoigt. Now that I recheck the 6 questions in [tag:casing-conventions], that probably should be a synonym of [tag:naming-conventions] as well.

Answer (score 29):

I say we save this tag. Sure, it looks like a rather lot of mess, but if you look closer you find some sanity to it.

This tag has a lot of meaning. Barring a few cases where the question is asking about collation, sorting, or codepoints, the good questions have a common theme. They're asking about special use of _ as a language form or convention in a particular language. The tag is meaningless without taking the language tag into account.

Partial summary:

C/C++: Leading _ symbols are reserved for internal globals, and __ is reserved for name mangling. As a consequence, _ can be safely be used for private members in almost all cases, but I don't see that much.

C#: _ appearing as a variable name for an out parameter means disregard; otherwise it's asking about coding conventions for which it occasionally borrows from C++ or uses leading _ to mean private member. It's also used as a comma surrogate in numeric literals.

Visual Basic: _ to mean private member is a well-regarded convention

Scala: some kind of scoped type hint

Python: hint for member "private" by convention

And on and on and on...

There are not too many questions, and we can actually clean this thing up really quickly where somebody tagged underscores while asking about the character as just another literal can have the tag removed and the rest remain. Of course the tag wiki needs to be updated. I propose:

> This tag is for asking about the meaning or well-established convention of use of the underscore character in a language. Always include the language tag. For JavaScript, you probably mean [underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore.js) for the library. For sort order, etc. you want [collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collation).

Here we note that in making the questions involving syntactic punctuation (and indeed it's less than half naming conventions) discoverable is advantageous. Since someone who doesn't know the answer has only the syntax to go on, using a tag for the symbol name and the language name is a good idea.

Comment: I somewhat agree with this. I did check the questions and half of the _ stuff is related to private scope, which makes it unambiguous. However, _ is also used in relation to the underscore symbol, which is why your suggestion of a cleanup makes sense. Probably, underscore needs to be renamed as underscore-methods, and then syn'd to [tag:private-members], in order to prevent this misuse?

Comment: @BhargavRao: I'm not going to get into a debate this late at night; but that only covers half the scope and well I'd rather the tag be discoverable to someone who is asking the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. There's no need to lose sleep over burns.

Comment: @Joshua This is what a synonym is for. Type in *underscore* and find the new tag. The problem is the tag is too ambiguous as-is. If I want a regex to find the underscore character, my use is as valid as any you've mentioned here, while not really being the same thing. Relying on the excerpt is expecting people to self-police, a tactic that has not proven successful in the past ([[seo\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo) and [[carbon\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym) come to mind)

Comment: @Machavity: Bad questions have bad tags, but do good questions?

Comment: @Joshua I think tags should be as intuitive as possible. While not all bad Qs are the result of tags, a confusing tag can lead to posting vague Qs (i.e. why [car] is now [r-car]). But you make a good point about usage, so straight burn is out. I've posted an answer that I think splits the difference, keeping the useful part of the tag while not encouraging people to post vague questions

Comment: A small nitpick, but in Python the double-underscore triggers name mangling to avoid naming conflicts in subclasses also a single underscore in the interactive Python interpreter represents the result of the last executed statement.

Comment: `The tag is meaningless w/o taking the language tag into account.`  Doesn't that make it a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)?

Comment: @jpyams: No. The meaning is reliably defined.

Comment: From your examples here, it seems the two usages of underscores are either name mangling, or code conventions. So.. in the cases of name mangling, we should tag it as such. For cases of code conventions, the questions are likely to be off topic - and if not, don't need the underscore tag.

Comment: Unless things have changed since I last looked (which was 5+ years ago), a solo underscore is conventionally used for a value that will be ignored in Go (Go Language— https://golang.org/).  Whether it is sensible to tag a Go question with the underscores tag too is something I'd not want to pontificate on.

Comment: In Visual Basic, [`_` is also the line-continuation character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#Syntax).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Some of us are starting to see my point. There are so many more uses besides just naming conventions.

Comment: In kotlin `_` is used to indicate an unused lambda parameter

Comment: Thinking of a middle ground here. I think disambiguating the tag by retagging all the other usages of the tag which do not relate to the underscored-methods at first, and then deciding later what to do with the remaining questions (based on whether more than 75% of questions remain), would be the best way out here.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I took another look at the top page. If you also punted the naming conventions questions most of the remaining ones are _ methods but Scala, go, and VB.NET have _ as a real syntactic element and there's highly voted questions on them.

Comment: I spoke to a Scala gold badge user, who mentioned that there are 22 different uses of an underscore, and most of it doesn't even need a tag. But yeah, this is kinda a mess.

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest we do a cleanup and then rename the tag to [underscore-operator] (Bhargav's [underscore-methods] would seem to exclude special variable names). This helps to solve the root problem here, which is that there's two basic uses of the current tag

1. Questions where `_` is an operator or signifier in a programming language. These are similar enough to warrant a tag
2. Questions where `_` is part of a string. While these may be on-topic, we don't need a tag related to finding or using a specific character (where #1 doesn't apply). A clearer tag name would avoid this ambiguity

Comment: I am not sure about the renaming, because they are not usually "opeators" in the language (exc. Scala/Haskell/etc), they are usually syntacticly meaningful entities or conventions but without an "operation" meaning: e.g., referring to the `_` in a C# `1_000_000` number as an *operator* would not be intuitive or meaningful, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

## Progress:

The [underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores) tag is in the process of being cleaned and disambiguated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and retagging using the following observations:

- [magic-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-methods) -  for the dunder methods, like `__str__`, which are "magically" called when `str` is called.
- [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) - For the `_` method in [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).
- [underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore.js) - for the Underscore.js related questions.
- [underscores-wp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores-wp) - for the Underscores theme in WordPress.
- [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) - for the usage of underscore in variable names and snake case, if warranted. In many cases, the [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore) can just be dropped.
- Leave the tag on the question if the question is related to the underscored methods (private members).
- Remove the tag in the other scenarios. (If you feel that a particular usage is prominent enough to require a separate tag, please leave a comment on this post).

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about retagging;just flag/close the question it is attached to.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score -4):

The only reason I can think of that it would be useful is, perhaps, helping people who search Google for underscore-related questions. It's hard to search for a literal `_`. But, people who would go to the trouble to use the `underscore` tag could just as easily type the word "underscore" in the question title or body to get visibility on Google.