# Should we burninate the [double-underscore] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across to the [double-underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-underscore) tag due to the recent [underscores burninate request which was declined and it was decided that the tag should be kept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333037). It has totally 25 questions; none of them are closed.

The tag seems useless to me. Its description says that:

> Use this tag for questions related to a Double Underscore, i.e. `__`.

However, tags should be used to help define the topic of the question and not what it contains.

So, according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380377) answer by Bhargav Rao:

- [magic-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-methods) tag can be used for the dunder methods, like `__str__`, which are "magically" called when `str` is called.

and some other tags can be used where appropriate.

The burnination criteria (although there are hundreds of similar occasions):

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, as it differs from language to language. The tag is used often in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions, function name questions, etc.

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Well, programming questions which contain `__` as mentioned, should be retagged. And, eh, questions about `__` themselves should not be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

> 3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. Questions about `__` in Python, are Python questions, questions about `__` in Java questions, are Java questions, and going on...

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

It refers to `__`, but has a different meaning depending on the language

So, I say the tag should be burninated.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that SE search doesn't handle searching for those characters "well" , so while I'm impartial about this request, having a tag might be one way to find and categorize those questions about special characters.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the 4 criteria for burnination this tag is also a meta-tag and meta-tags seem to be actively discouraged in SO.

I will quote the tag wiki:

> Since [double-underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-underscore) is used in its general meaning, you are strongly encouraged to use one or more additional tags to better describe your specific case.

These kinds of tags are actively discouraged in SO this tag fits both descriptions of a meta tag as specified in [The death of meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.

This is explicitly mentioned in the tag wiki

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Seeing the tagged questions one can see that double underscore means different things to different people. To me it means PHP magic methods. It also seems to mean something similar (but different) to python users.

I do therefore think we should burninate this tag.

Answer (score -6):

Double underscores are a rare enough syntactic element that we should be able to write a single canonical answer for each language tag and burn away the tag altogether.