# The [comma] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I think the tag [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) should be burninated.

### Does it describe the contents, is it unambiguous?

In a sense, the contents have a comma somewhere in there. It is ambiguous because knowing there is a comma is wholly worthless to the actual question.

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No, it is just a character.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I guess it does as a list separator or decimal indicator in some localities. In this case I think we can safely ignore those commonalities.

This is the description:

> Comma ',' is used to indicate a separation of elements within a list, such as an array, or parameters accepted by a function.

You have to go to the sixteenth top user to get someone with >3 answered questions.

There are 1337 questions asked with this tag, which is pretty leet. It has 9 watchers.

Comment: While I don't mind burninating this tag -- it seems totally useless after all -- I wonder whether this is the best use of volunteer resources.  Because, while this tag is useless, it also seems harmless, because it doesn't mislead anybody into tagging their questions wrongly.  Much worse are **ambiguous tags**: generic-sounding tags that get used for completely unrelated technologies instead of the proper tags for those technologies.

Comment: For comparison, consider the tag [tag:jsonserializer].  The guidance mentions a [Java JSONSerializer](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/flexjson/JSONSerializer.html) but many questions related to Json.NET's `JsonSerializer` and System.Text.Json's `JsonSerializer` are getting tagged with it **and not tagged with the proper tags [tag:json.net] and [tag:system.text.json]**.  That means that subject matter experts who watch the proper tags may never notice the tagged questions and provide answers.

Comment: And yet, ambiguous tags aren't worthless because the relevant technologies need tagging to attract answers.  They are, instead, worse than useless, because they fulfill a need wrongly.

Comment: I'd like to focus more on those sorts of misleading, possibly harmful tags, instead of meaningless "noise" tags.  (Should I make that an answer)?

Comment: When you burninate a tag, do the questions that use that tag automatically have it removed?

Comment: @LogicalBranch Not in this case, no. Removing the tag is part of the burnination process, at least for content that isn't off-topic and needs to be closed and possibly deleted.

Comment: There are more puntuation tags.  [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period), [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma), [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon), [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen), and [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space). They are all fewer than 1000 posts, except [space] tag.

Comment: @coutHelloworldendl This burn is still only about comma, though. We'll cover the remaining tags when we get there

Answer (score 81):

For programming related uses we have [comma-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma-operator), so I don't see much use for plain [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma).

Also, **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
I'd say far from it. Depending on a language and context, it can mean a myriad of different things:

- comma operator (C, C++)
- decimal separator (Excel or anything locale aware)
- tuple declaration (Python)
- function arguments separator
- data structure elements separator
- variable declarations separator
- ... and probably more

Comment: I won the debate to save underscore and it ended up with six questions. I don't feel like trying to save comma. Let it burn.

Comment: @Joshua I have to agree [your method here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380349) is what should be aimed at in this discussion. Hopefully someone can adapt from it an add some extra depth to this thread.

Comment: CSS list separator

Comment: There are also a [tag:separator] Tag and a [tag:punctuation] Tag that can be used...

Comment: @bad_coder don't know how you read Joshua, but I read it as "it's too much work to save punctuation tags, and no benefit at all"

Comment: @Joshua Saving `underscores` is great... but now we also have `underscore`... exact same thing but singular instead of plural, at least singular don't contains anything yet, it may be time to discuss that in another question.

Comment: @Lundin I think you probably meant [tag:csv] (comma-separated values,) not [tag:cvs] (the Concurrent Version System, not to be confused with the chain of pharmacies.)

Comment: @reirab Most definitely! Silly typo... well, that would be the first time that I recommend anyone to use CVS :)

Comment: @Joshua find solace that it was synonymized to underscore.js

Comment: @Braiam: turns out I mistyped it and the tag I was referring to is underscores not underscore.

Answer (score 18):

[comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about the comma operator used in multiple languages – including C, C++, JavaScript, and Perl – can be tagged [comma-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma-operator)
- Questions about csv files or processing comma separated values can be tagged [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv)
- Questions about formatting numbers to use a comma as either the thousands or decimal separator can be tagged [number-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting)
- Not all uses for commas need to have its own tag if one doesn't already exist.

## Progress:

The [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=comma),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomma%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomma%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomma%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomma%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=405831)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: You wrote, *Questions about formatting numbers to use a comma as either the thousands or decimal separator can be tagged [tag:number-formatting]* but there is also a tag [tag:decimal-point] which does seem well defined.  Should the former always be preferred over the latter?

Comment: @dbc I didn't edit that bit in; as usual, common sense applies. If [decimal-point] makes more sense, use it. The observations are hints and not strict rules that must be followed to the letter, or else. Feel free to edit the answer to reflect its existence though

Answer (score 6):

While I don't mind burninating this tag -- it seems totally useless after all -- I wonder whether this is the best use of volunteer resources.  Because, while this tag is useless, it also seems harmless, because it doesn't mislead anybody into tagging their questions wrongly.  Much worse are **ambiguous tags**: generic-sounding tags that get used for completely unrelated technologies instead of the proper tags for those technologies.

For comparison, consider the tag [jsonserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonserializer).  The guidance mentions a [Java JSONSerializer](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/flexjson/JSONSerializer.html) but many questions related to Json.NET's `JsonSerializer` and System.Text.Json's `JsonSerializer` are getting tagged with it **and not tagged with the proper tags [json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net) and [system.text.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.text.json)**.  That means that subject matter experts who watch the proper tags may never notice the tagged questions and provide answers.

And yet, ambiguous tags aren't worthless because the relevant technologies need tagging to attract answers.  They are, instead, worse than useless, because they fulfill a need wrongly.

I'd like to focus more on disambiguating those sorts of misleading, harmful yet necessary tags, instead of meaningless "noise" tags.

(This is really just a "discussion" answer.  No defense of [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) is intended by this answer.)

Comment: I understand the argument of prioritizing tags that are more harmful for being potentially misleading, **but** the `comma` tag is noise (that alone makes for a good burnination) and what's more it's an easy burnination. If you go for `jsonserializer` the content starts becoming Java and .NET specific and that can narrow the field of available curators. I've programmed with both Java and .NET however even for me it's hard wrapping my head around those languages when I'm not working with them at present. My conclusion is an easy 1400 Q `comma` burnination seems easier to get done at the moment.

Comment: FWIW, there were also a bunch of questions tagged with *just* the `comma` tag, which effectively hides questions from virtually everyone once they fall off the front page.

Comment: @BSMP - oh that's interesting.  I hadn't considered that such a useless tag would be the **only** tag on a question.  That makes burninating useless tags seem more urgent.