# Puzzling [period] practices are prevalent. Proposing to pursue a passable plan to pause proliferation?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I recently noticed the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) is periodically being used in ways that do not conform with the tag description:

> A period of time is an interval, a span of time.

I realized that many uses of the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) tag would be in reference to the <kbd>.</kbd> punctuation character.  There were also some [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) questions that dealt with the period of a trigonometric (or other) function.

*(Personal aside:) There's already so much activity on SO that it seems hard to feel like one can contribute in a meaningful way.  Seeing as how the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) tag had a specific definition and that some old questions were misusing the tag - I thought I had found a way to help and clean up a dusty corner of SO.*

It is apparently bad form to clean-up mis-tags in a focused way on your own, as I ended up hearing from the moderators and had all of the tag-only edits that I had made reverted (*nearly 40 posts edited over the course of three weeks*).  The encouragement was to bring the question up here on Meta, before proceeding further...

So I started doing some reading and found a few prime proposals per the proper perpetuation (or pausing) of the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) tagging practice...  And I thought I'd list them here for discussion:

1. Periodically **purify the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) tag** from questions that are
   mis-tagged (i.e. don't refer to a period of time)
2. **Polish up our use of the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) tag** [by disambiguation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405831/conflagrate-comma#comment830061_405831) (e.g. change the tags to be [time-period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-period) and [function-period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-period), etc.)
3. **Purge the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) tag** altogether [through burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405831/conflagrate-comma#comment830006_405831)
4. Propose yet **some other method to deal with that tag, [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period)**.

My apologies if my first Meta question was not properly put-together!

***EDIT:***
In my response to the moderators, I mentioned that I fully intended to leave the "period" tag on all questions that referred to:

- working with a period of time
- working with intervals of time
- code using a Period object
- (I was even leaving it on questions that deal with) how to implement something with regularity

Perhaps those perogatives pass for proper [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) placement?

Comment: Advocating artful alliteration.  Altogether astounding! +1

Comment: Facetiously fault a fairy tale for the fabulous failure frequency of the first feasible [full stops](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_stop#Noun)? ([More words](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) (starting from *"F-15"*).)

Comment: Perhaps provide some examples of proper use of the [\[period\] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) (if ap-propriate)?

Comment: We don't need this tag.  [Period]

Comment: I vote for burnination

Comment: [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) has a "[Period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html)" class. But even that may not be appropriate for a tag. Proceed with [propane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propane#Portable_stoves)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I've added the cases where I thought the period tag did not need to be removed - thanks for the good suggestion!

Comment: I feel dizzy from reading the title :3

Comment: One downside to the nice title: the key part `[period]` is cut off with ... in the "featured on meta" sidebar, so I had to open the link to see what the question was about.  Perhaps period's position can be promoted, perhaps to a prefix?  (Or not actually a prefix, just earlier.)

Comment: Decidedly derided durations definitely due disintegration.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Yes, that is a proper prophylactic proposal.

Comment: Useless Tag, do we have SME's in `Number` / `String` / `Array` / `Date` Objects that master all Prog-Langs using those 4 "Universal" Objects...? + `Addition` for "1+1", + `Concatenation` for "per+iod", etc, `period` as defined in the Tag is simply a Subtraction between 2 `Date` (Time) Objects... And it's the same Concept in all Prog-Langs, only the Syntax is sometimes a bit different...

Comment: Now I imagine you saying that with a mouth full of food. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CuYtN0mRf0

Comment: *"SME"* = *subject-matter expert*

Comment: @Gimby: Speaking of [Martin Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Landau), ***all*** 48 episodes of *[Space: 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%3A_1999)* ("Moonbase Alpha") are on YouTube. [Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un7FB2XjVos&list=PLHloTpmV7roN0VBdaUbyr4w9nYtATaP06).