# The [colon] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I think we should burninate the [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag for the [same reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405831/13552470) we burninated the [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) tag:

### Does it describe the contents, is it unambiguous?

In a sense, the contents have a colon somewhere in there. It is
ambiguous because knowing there is a colon is wholly worthless to the
actual question.

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No, it is just a character.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

The current tag wiki-excerpt of the tag is:

> This tag refers to the ASCII colon (:) character.

There are currently 320 questions tagged with the [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag.

Comment: There might be an issue, removing the **colon**: the colon can be used as a single character, like for showing inheritance, like in this C# source code `public class Flow : View`. It can also be used for showing namespaces, like in this other C# source code example `global::System.Runtime`. Therefore I believe it might be useful keeping that tag.

Comment: @Dominique Are the [tag:inheritance] and [tag:namespaces] tags insufficient in these cases? Does the [tag:colon] tag add anything if one of the others is present?

Comment: Sorry for earlier. While the use of the tag all seem to relate to the punctuation mark, the punctuation mark will have different meanings in different contexts and I can't understand why these should be associated. Substitute in other character names to see the generic silliness of this approach.

Comment: @Dominique in PHP `::` has a specific name: `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592322/php-expects-t-paamayim-nekudotayim so the colon tag can safely be omitted in that regard at least :-)

Comment: I could imagine someone being a subject matter expert in colons, but if they are, they're probably on the wrong site. :)

Comment: @beaker: I'm referring to a beginner's question like "*I know that a colon is used for inheritance, but in my code there are two subsequent colons. What kind of inheritance is that?*" :-)

Comment: The reason we do not allow burnination requests to have punny titles while they are "featured" is because, when they are featured, they appear in the sidebar (yellow box) on all pages. We want those titles to be clear, not clickbait. Additionally, we want users who are unfamiliar with Meta culture to understand what is being proposed, and the gravity of what is being proposed, so that they can weigh in with any reasons why *not* to remove the tag. It is not because we hate fun, but because once a request reaches this stage, clear communication is more important than fun.

Answer (score 11):

[colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about the `::` operator in a scope resolution context can use the [scope-resolution-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope-resolution-operator) tag. Examples of languages where this apply are C++ and PHP

  - Questions about namespaces in particular may additionally be tagged [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespaces)
  - Questions about XML namespaces should use [xml-namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-namespaces) instead
- Questions about Java's (and other JVM languages') `::` operator should be tagged [method-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-reference)
- Other `::` operators may have tags already. However, there's not always a point in creating unique tags for each use of each operator in every context, as these tags often act as a meta tag.
- Questions about inheritance should be tagged [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance)
- Questions merely about the character does not need any special tags beyond relevant tech tags
- Equivalently, questions about semicolons do not need special tags (again, they need relevant tech  tags), unless it's about an established operator. A language tag should always be present
- Questions about matlab's `:` operator can be tagged [matlab-colon-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-colon-operator)

## Progress:

The [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=colon),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolon%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolon%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolon%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolon%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=418577)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: The retag guidance suggests to use [tag:scope-resolution-operator] for `::` when used in scope resolution, but [this c# question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59664453/3744182) already uses [tag:global-namespace] -- which has more questions.  Which is correct?

Comment: @dbc This is a solid edge-case, and the short answer is, I don't entirely know. I was under the impression C# used `::` for all scope resolution as well, but they use `.`, which in this context is a scope resolution operator. [tag:global-namespace] sounds pretty useless in my opinion, because `::` is still a form of scope resolution, but C# just happens to associate `::` to be relative to the global scope rather than the current scope. And questions about global namespace itself would be a [namespaces]-worthy questions

Comment: But no idea whether it should be tagged [scope-resolution-operator] or not. I removed the guidance on C# until this is clarified, but it sounds like a judgement call moment by you or another SME on whether or not it qualifies as a scope resolution operator

Comment: Hmm, I don't actually think c# has a name for the `.` character that separates namespaces, and doesn't have a named concept for a "scope resolution operator".  Turns out that, in c#. `::` is called the [namespace alias operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) -- something I didn't even know until I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231824).

Comment: I guess questions about Java's `::` operator should be tagged using [[method-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-reference)]?

Comment: @dan1st yep. Tried looking for that tag, and couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

There is one valid use-case that appears to have been overlooked here, the colon is actually an operator in MATLAB: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

I believe we should halt this retagging until we have decided what to do in this regard; I suggest a new tag, `matlab-colon-operator`.

Comment: There's 14 affected questions (including closed). That isn't enough to stop the burn, nor to justify the tag. It's trivial to make another tag for the retaggable questions, assuming it doesn't already exist and is actually significant enough to warrant a tag

Comment: Also, surprise retag targets are handled on the fly. We don't stop burns just because a new retag target appears. Tags can be created without needing a discussion if deemed necessary

Answer (score -4):

I think a good question to ask in cases like this is does the tag help newbies?

If I am just starting out learning my first programming language, and

- I'm getting a syntax error on a colon character,
- I want to ask about why we use `::` instead of `:` for something, or
- I want to ask about processing data which contains colons

does the colon tag help with any of

- the asker finding a similar-enough question and just going there?
- the eople looking to answer questions they're good at? or
- people checking for duplicate questions? (Contrary to popular belief sometimes those people *do* find a question that is close enough to be considered a duplicate or at least helpful to the asker!)

In particular, I think newbies are much more likely to be able to say "I've got a problem with a colon" and think to search for "colon" as a tag (especially since tags are such a mainstream social media UI/UX thing) than to think "I've got a question about [inheritance syntax / scope resolution syntax / namespace syntax / ternary operator syntax / parsing field separators]".

Comment: Question titles could still list the word "colon" even when talking about inheritence, it is just not suitable as a tag

Comment: The [tag:syntax] tag already covers this. Otherwise you get a tag for every character you might encounter in code